# hide a div on clicking the body other than the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide all div's hide when clicked on the body of the page other than the div.
my div is

```
<div id="settingsBoxExpand">
                    <div id="settings1" class="settingsBoxExpandItem" style="padding:3px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd">My Account</div>
                    <div id="settings2" class="settingsBoxExpandItem" style="padding:3px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd">Preferences</div>
                    <div id="settings3" class="settingsBoxExpandItem" style="padding:3px;">Logout</div>
                </div>
```

and on clicking the settingsBoxExpand div in will be slides down. 
i need to hide this on clicking any other position other than settingsBoxExpand div.
i have 3 more similar div's.
tried

```
$('body:not(#settingsBoxExpand)').click(function(){
            $("#settingsBoxExpand").hide();
        });
```

but its not working.
"not" doesn't works for me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is trying to filter the list of `body` elements found into the ones that do not have the id of `settingsBoxExpand` (which is most likely zero unless you have a `body` element with an id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the body (or document) to hide the box on click and stop the click events on the div from bubbling up the DOM and triggering a body click event:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    $("#settingsBoxExpand").hide();
});

$('#settingsBoxExpand').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

By placing the .hide() as part of the click handler for the body, it will hide the div when click events bubble up the DOM and reach the body. With .stopPropagation you prevent the event from reaching the body.

Event capturing and bubbling is important to understand with more advanced event handling; here's a little more reading if you're interested:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano Yes, you can accomplish this without jQuery, but browsers handle event binding and event bubbling cancellation in different ways. If you want to easily support multiple browsers, then using jQuery is a good choice.