# Detect click outside textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angular

When the user enters text in my textarea, my window changes color. I want that when it clicks outside the textarea, it replaces color as before.

```
<textarea class="chat-input"
              id="textarea"
              rows="2" cols="50"
              (keyup)="detectTextarea($event)">
</textarea>


detectTextarea(event: any): any {
   this.changeColor = true;
   var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
}
```

/////////UPDATE////////////
It does not work :

```
detectTextarea(event: any): any {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

  textarea.addEventListener("focus", function( event ) {
    this.changeColor = true;
  }, true);
  textarea.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    this.changeColor = false;
  }, true);
}
```

Comment: This might help you. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390171/hide-a-div-on-clicking-the-body-other-than-the-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
<textarea class="chat-input"
    id="textarea"
    rows="2" cols="50"
    (focus)="func()"
    (blur)="otherFunc()"
    (keyup)="detectTextarea($event)">
</textarea>
```

and then:

```
func() {
    this.changeColor = true;
  }
  otherFunc() {
    this.changeColor = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Finally it was simple :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) event to know when the user exit the textarea.

Comment: 10k, congratulations)